# What is a difference between pyWorkPage and pyWorkCover page in Pega?

Tags: pega

The page displayed on Clipboard `pyWorkPage` and `pyWorkCover`.

Can you tell me the difference between them? And let me from where I will get complete data to read about the Clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume an application which has two work types: Order and Approval. Their work classes would be `Edu-SampleApp-Work-Order` and `Edu-SampleApp-Work-Approval`. Furthermore one Order needs one or more Approvals which are spinned of as subcases (that is separate business process objects).

`pyWorkPage` always refers to the current work object you are performing. If you are creating / processing an Order this Order object will be held in the current thread under the name `pyWorkPage`. When the approver opens an Approval workobject (different thread) this Approval object will be opened into `pyWorkPage`. Additionally, since Approval knows the instance key to it's parent case (the corresponding order) it will open this parent case into the page `pyWorkCover`.

Which means:

- `pyWorkPage` will be of a class in your application layer (`Edu-SampleApp-Work-Order` or `Edu-SampleApp-Work-Approval`) which then derives from `Work-` or `Work-Cover-`.
- `pyWorkCover` is of a class in your application layer (`Edu-SampleApp-Work-Approval`) which then derives from `Work-Cover-`

The other answer saying the page would contain the Assignment is wrong, since assignments are instance of a class derived from the `Assign-` class, typically `Assign-Worklist` or `Assign-Workbasket` class.

Some info:

- [PDN Case Management Overview](https://pdn.pega.com/case-management/case-management-overview)
- [PRPC Help: Understanding Covers](https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v61sp2/procomhelpmain.htm#concepts/concepts2/conceptscovers.htm)
- [PRPC Help: Subcase Definition](https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v717/procomhelpmain.htm#definitions/s/subcase.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Harness forms are displayed with the standard activity `@baseclass.Show-Harness`. This activity expects to find (by convention) objects on the page names:

- `pyWorkPage` - conventional name for the page that contains a work item. This page usually has a class derived from the `Work-Object-` class.
- `pyWorkCover` - conventional name for the page that contains an assignment object. This page has a class derived from the `Assign-` base class.

You can find a lot about using Clipboard tool here: [Using the Clipboard tool](https://pdn.pega.com/node/49276).

Comment: Please see my answer, the class of `pyWorkCover` does **not** inherit from `Assign-`. Its class inherits from some class inheriting from `Work-Cover-` or directly from `Work-Cover-`.

Additionally `Assign-` should not be called base class - `@baseclass` is the base class.